# TensorFlow - expected global_average_pooling2d_1_input to have shape (1, 1, 2048) but got array with shape (7, 7, 2048)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm fairly new to TensorFlow and Image Classification, so I may be missing key knowledge and is probably why I'm facing this issue.

I've built a `ResNet50` model in TensorFlow for the purpose of image classification of Dog Breeds, using the `ImageNet` library and I have successfully trained a neural network which can detect various Dog Breeds.

I'm now at the point in which I would like to pass a random image of a dog to my model for it to spit out an output on what it thinks the dog breed is. However, when I run this function, `dog_breed_predictor("dogImages/dogImages/valid/016.Beagle/Beagle_01126.jpg")`, I get the error `expected global_average_pooling2d_1_input to have shape (1, 1, 2048) but got array with shape (7, 7, 2048)` when it tries to execute the line `Resnet50_model.predict(bottleneck_feature)` and I don't know how to get around this.

Here's the code. I've provided all that I feel is relevant to the problem.

```
#import tensorflow as tf, etc.

from sklearn.datasets import load_files
np_utils = tf.keras.utils

# define function to load train, test, and validation datasets
def load_dataset(path):
    data = load_files(path)
    dog_files = np.array(data['filenames'])
    dog_targets = np_utils.to_categorical(np.array(data['target']), 133)
    return dog_files, dog_targets

# load train, test, and validation datasets
train_files, train_targets = load_dataset('dogImages/dogImages/train')
valid_files, valid_targets = load_dataset('dogImages/dogImages/valid')
test_files, test_targets = load_dataset('dogImages/dogImages/test')

#define Resnet50 model
Resnet50_model = ResNet50(weights="imagenet")

def path_to_tensor(img_path):
    #loads RGB image as PIL.Image.Image type
    img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
    #convert PIL.Image.Image type to 3D tensor with shape (224, 224, 3)
    x = image.img_to_array(img)
    #convert 3D tensor into 4D tensor with shape (1, 224, 224, 3)
    return np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)

from keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions

def ResNet50_predict_labels(img_path):
    #returns prediction vector for image located at img_path
    img = preprocess_input(path_to_tensor(img_path))
    return np.argmax(Resnet50_model.predict(img))

###returns True if a dog is detected in the image stored at img_path
def dog_detector(img_path):
    prediction = ResNet50_predict_labels(img_path)
    return ((prediction <= 268) & (prediction >= 151))

###Obtain bottleneck features from another pre-trained CNN
bottleneck_features = np.load("bottleneck_features/DogResnet50Data.npz")
train_DogResnet50 = bottleneck_features["train"]
valid_DogResnet50 = bottleneck_features["valid"]
test_DogResnet50 = bottleneck_features["test"]

###Define your architecture
Resnet50_model = tf.keras.Sequential()
Resnet50_model.add(tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(input_shape=train_DogResnet50.shape[1:]))
Resnet50_model.add(tf.contrib.keras.layers.Dense(133, activation="softmax"))

Resnet50_model.summary()

###Compile the model
Resnet50_model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="rmsprop", metrics=["accuracy"])
###Train the model
checkpointer = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath="saved_models/weights.best.ResNet50.hdf5",
                                                 verbose=1, save_best_only=True)

Resnet50_model.fit(train_DogResnet50, train_targets,
                  validation_data=(valid_DogResnet50, valid_targets),
                  epochs=20, batch_size=20, callbacks=[checkpointer])

###Load the model weights with the best validation loss.
Resnet50_model.load_weights("saved_models/weights.best.ResNet50.hdf5")

###Calculate classification accuracy on the test dataset
Resnet50_predictions = [np.argmax(Resnet50_model.predict(np.expand_dims(feature, axis=0))) for feature in test_DogResnet50]

#Report test accuracy
test_accuracy = 100*np.sum(np.array(Resnet50_predictions)==np.argmax(test_targets, axis=1))/len(Resnet50_predictions)
print("Test accuracy: %.4f%%" % test_accuracy)

from extract_bottleneck_features import * #separate .py file

def dog_breed(img_path):
    #extract bottleneck features
    bottleneck_feature = extract_Resnet50(path_to_tensor(img_path))
    #obtain predicted vector
    predicted_vector = Resnet50_model.predict(bottleneck_feature)
    #return dog breed that is predicted by the model
    return dog_names[np.argmax(predicted_vector)]

def dog_breed_predictor(img_path):
    #determine the predicted dog breed
    breed = dog_breed(img_path)
    #display the image
    img = cv2.imread(img_path)
    cv_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    plt.imshow(cv_rgb)
    plt.show()
    #display relevant predictor result
    if dog_detector(img_path):
        print("This is a dog and its breed is: " + str(breed))
    elif face_detector(img_path):
        print("This is a human but it looks like a: " + str(breed))
    else:
        print("I don't know what this is.")

dog_breed_predictor("dogImages/dogImages/valid/016.Beagle/Beagle_01126.jpg") #shape error occurs here
```

Function from extract_bottleneck_features.py:

```
def extract_Resnet50(tensor):
    from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50, preprocess_input
    return ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False).predict(preprocess_input(tensor))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `pooling == 'avg'` or `pooling == 'max'` with `include_top=False` as arguments in your call to ResNet. It will take care of your pooling layer. You can remove your pooling layer after you call the function with those parameters. 
From the [source code](https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/blob/master/resnet50.py#L235):

```
if include_top:
    x = Flatten()(x)
    x = Dense(classes, activation='softmax', name='fc1000')(x)
else:
    if pooling == 'avg':
        x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    elif pooling == 'max':
        x = GlobalMaxPooling2D()(x)
```

Comment: I've changed it to "include_top=True" but now the error has changed to `expected global_average_pooling2d_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1000)`. Any ideas?

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize you were training your own classifier, I will update my answer, you should use it with include_top=False

Comment: So I need to remove `Resnet50_model.add(tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(input_shape=train_DogResnet50.shape[1:]))` from my model definition and instead add `pooling="avg"` or `pooling="max"` in my ResNet call?

Answer (score -1):

Firstly there are two model named as `Resnet50_model`. One is `ResNet50()` to categorize the image as dog, the other you set

```
###Define your architecture
Resnet50_model = tf.keras.Sequential()
Resnet50_model.add(tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(input_shape=train_DogResnet50.shape[1:]))
Resnet50_model.add(tf.contrib.keras.layers.Dense(133, activation="softmax"))
```

is tunning from `ResNet50()` to categorize into dog species, which you should rename it.

data loaded from `bottleneck_features/DogResnet50Data.npz` with dimension as (1,1,2048), while what you get from `extract_Resnet50(path_to_tensor(img_path))` with dimension as (1,2048) you may edit as

```
def Resnet50_predict_breed(img_path):
    # extract bottleneck features
    bottleneck_feature = np.expand_dims(np.expand_dims(
        extract_Resnet50(path_to_tensor(img_path)), axis=0), axis=0)
    ...
```

or you can get your own bottleneck_features with

```
def paths_to_tensor(img_paths):
    list_of_tensors = [path_to_tensor(img_path) for img_path in tqdm(img_paths)]
    return np.vstack(list_of_tensors)

def extract_Resnet50(tensor):
    from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50, preprocess_input
    ResNet50(weights='imagenet', input_shape=(224,224,3), pooling='avg', include_top=False).predict(preprocess_input(tensor))

train_Resnet50 = extract_Resnet50(paths_to_tensor(train_files))[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis,:]
valid_Resnet50 = extract_Resnet50(paths_to_tensor(valid_files))[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis,:]
test_Resnet50 = extract_Resnet50(paths_to_tensor(test_files))[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis,:]

def Resnet50_predict_breed(img_path):
    # extract bottleneck features
    bottleneck_feature = np.expand_dims(np.expand_dims(
        extract_Resnet50(path_to_tensor(img_path)), axis=0), axis=0)
    ...
```